# My JButton stays on the screen after being pressed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

My JButton's code is here:

```
JButton b = new JButton("JButton");
b.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 50);
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 500);
    }
});
frame.add(b);
```

This should make my screen go black after my button is pressed, but the button just stays on my JFrame. I can't find what is going wrong with this JButton, as I have in the past.
Another error I am encountering is that my JButton takes up the whole screen, even though I set its bounds to be a specific area.

Comment: why should the button vanish? there is no code to do so

Comment: you never write code that hides the button ... what makes you think it would(should) disappear all of the sudden?

Comment: @Stultuske, this is just for practice, and why not? I don't use JButtons often so I felt like the `g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 500);` would hide the JButton.

Comment: no. consider it like this: you are standing on a brick floor, someone pours a bucket of red paint over the floor. your shoes might get a bit red, but you'll still be standing there, unless you actually step aside

Comment: @Stultuske that would mean that my second error is why I can't see my black screen that I would wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably degine the `Graphics g` before the `JButton b`, thus the JButton is always displayed on the top layer.

You have to explicitely hide the button on the click action using the [setVisible(false)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setVisible(boolean)) method.

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        b.setVisible(false);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked for a different class with a JButton in it, but not this one.